# Bounding a triple integral

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I'm studying for an exam and I struggle with finding the bounds for triple integrals. Specifically, I find it difficult when I can not draw a picture of the surface (which I may not have time to do on my exam anyway).

I am trying to do the following:

Find the volume of the surface bounded by $$z = \sin(x+y) + 1 - x^2 - y^2$$ and $$z = \sin(x+y) - 2y$$

So I know that I need to set the $z$s equal to each other and find the intersection to get the "shadow" that the surface casts onto the $xy$ plane. Then I use that to find the bounds for x and y.

Setting $z = z$, I get $x^2+y^2-2y = 1$

Without using a picture of the graph, how can I find the bounds for $x$ and $y$ using this equation?

Also, my professor suggests doing the integral over the vertical variable (z in this case) first, before trying to find the bounds for the other variables (then just doing a double integral). If I haven't found the bounds for the others yet, and I don't know what the region looks like, how do I determine which is the upper bound vs. lower bound for $z$?

It seems I should choose a point inside the region $x^2+y^2-2y = 1$ and put it into the two equations. But how do I know that a point is inside that region?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The upper and lower bounds for $z$ in the triple integral would be the two functions you started with. So integrating w.r.t. $z$ would just add the step of subtracting the lower bound from the upper bound, as you've already done.

*Hint*: notice that if you complete the square for $y$ in the equation $$x^2+y^2-2y=1$$ you get a circle in the $xy$-plane. This is the "shadow" you referred to.

Comment: Yes, my question was more of which of the equations was upper and which was lower. In this case I could just set them equal to each other and avoid doing the integral.  But what if the integrand was not 1? Then I would have to determine which was which to do the integral.

Comment: If the integrand is some function $f(x,y,z)$, then integrating w.r.t. $z$ gives $F(x,y,z_1)-F(x,y,z_0)$, where $z_1$ is the upper bound and $z_0$ is the lower bound. This will be a function of $x$ and $y$ - do you need help with those bounds?